# How would you say "valid from [a date] onwards"?

Tags: time, informal

I'm not quite sure how to say the following in German, despite googling and looking at dictionaries for a while.

> Call me (from the 20th onwards)

I basically want to tell the recipient of the email that my phone will only work from the 20th onwards. The best I can come up with is

> Rufen Sie mich an (vom 20. an.) or (vom 20. ab)

but it doesn't sound correct to me.

Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
Durand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several possibilities, including your first version:

> vom 20. an
>   ab dem 20.
>   nicht vor dem 20.
>   nach dem 19.

However, the separated prefix of *anrufen* must be at the very end of the sentence:

> Rufen Sie mich *ab dem 20.* an.

This makes *vom 20. an* quite awkward due to the repetition *an an*, so one of the other options would be preferred in this particular sentence.

Answer (score 6):

> Rufen Sie mich ab dem 20. an.

oder

> Rufen Sie mich vom 20. ab an.

Also bis auf den Satzbau schon richtig, aber das *anrufen* wird aufgesplittet, und das *an* ganz ans Ende gesetzt.

> *Rufen Sie mich* mit Ihrem neuen Smartphone ab dem 20., aber nicht nach 17 Uhr zuhause mit Ihrer schönen Stimme *an*.

Eine Richtung muss man bei der Zeit noch nicht angeben, denn wir können vom 20. ab noch nicht zurück in der Zeit reisen - sobald wir es können, wird dieser Satz hier aber hinfällig sein.

> Gurten Sie sich ab 1200 m aufwärts, also über der Baumgrenze, zur Sicherheit an.

Hier ist eine Richtung schon sinnvoller.

Comment: "vom 20. ab" klingt irgendwie nicht Deutsch.

Comment: `Ruf mich nach dem 19. an` wäre korrekt aber so ökonomisch-mathematisch spricht kaum ein Mensch. `Ruf mich nach dem 20. an oder an diesem` wäre auch richtig aber zu lang und manchem zu kompliziert. `Vom 20. ab anrufen` scheint mir die Probleme nicht zu haben und valides Deutsch. Was ist daran falsch? Dass es `irgendwie nicht deutsch klingt` ist mir irgendwie zu schwammig.

Comment: Danke schön! Das war interessant zu lesen.

Comment: Ich (Muttersprachler) habe "vom 20. ab" noch nie gelesen/gehört. Hätte das jetzt auch als falsch bezeichnet. Wird das vielleicht nur in bestimmten Regionen verwendet?

Comment: @unor: Bemerkenswert, dass Du Dich bei so gewöhnlichen Begriffen an Dein ganzes Leben erinnern kannst. `Rufen Sie mich vom 20. an an.` würdest Du akzeptieren? `Ab Montag bin ich in Urlaub` auch?